# How to migrate from mdadm to storage spaces?

Tags: debian, windows-server-2016, software-raid, storage-spaces

I have:

Debian linux server
4 TB 3x(2TB drives) mdamd raid5 with EXT4 filesystem.

I want to upgrade it to:

Windows server 2016 with storage spaces - 6TB(2 x 6TB drives in mirror) NTFS.

What would be the best approach? I am thinking of installing Windows server with linux guest vm and copy data over SMB. I cannot install and use type 1 hypervisor due to old server hardware.

Answer (score 2):

1) Backup your data (proper backups like say Veeam will ensure data integrity thru checksums)

2) Install Windows and configure Storage Spaces

3) Restore your content from backup

P.S. What you do is a big mistake IMHO. You might dislike mdadm but I'd suggest FreeBSD+ZFS instead of Windows+SS+NTFS.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I already have onsite and offsite backups but not all data is included. I am asking about MOVING from one array to another. I cannot use additional disks. Personalty i would gladly use btrfs and call it a day :) But i need a DC.